# Is it possible to change the value of symbols(entries) in kallsyms in Linux dynamically?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to change the value of symbols(entries) in kallsyms in Linux dynamically? I am trying to change the value of `ret_from_fork` symbol while inserting a linux kernel module.

Comment: What does it mean: to change the value of the symbol? Do you want to change associated address? For what reason?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the associated address. The ret_from_fork is a symbol that a child process will jump to right after clone/fork/vfork. So I want change the address of ret_from_fork to a symbol in my Linux kernel module so that my kernel module will be able to capture a new process generates. After that, my code will jump back to the original address of ret_from_fork, so clone/fork/vfork can return back to userspace.

Comment: Have you heard about kprobes?

Comment: I know a little bit about kprobes. However, what I am currently doing is not using GPL license.